# Keep track of GameObject's position in array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array of Images, each representing a different "level".  I need to know which level a user chose from the game selection screen.  I don't understand why this doesn't work--the code logs the total number of images each time, i.e., the final index in the loop.  (If there is a totally better way of handling this, I'm open).

```
void Start()
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (Texture2D texture in imageTextures)
    {
        Image image = Instantiate(levelSelectPrefab, levelSelectPanel);
        Button button = image.GetComponent<Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(delegate { StartGame(texture, index); });
        index++;
    }
}

    public void StartGame(Texture2D jigsawTexture, int index)
    {
        Debug.Log("chosen puzzle index: " + index);
    }
```

Comment: is it only ever spawning the last level in the array?

Comment: @BugFinder I can choose any of the levels to play, as expected, but I don't know how to keep track of which of the 24 levels the user chose.

Comment: ok so this had nothing to do with any of it - as Im surprised it didnt jsut always give you the last texture of the list each time.. cos normally you need to make local copy of the variable...  exactly then what isnt working? as theres nothing here to remember levels...

Comment: @BugFinder The Debug.Log always prints out 24, the total number of images.  I expected it to print the index of the for-loop when it was passed in.

Comment: It's possible I'm solving the wrong problem.  The user is able to replay previously beaten levels, but I need to know if they've beaten the final available level so I can unlock the next one.  I'm keeping track of how many levels have been beaten, so my thought was to compare the index to the number of levels beaten to see whether or not to make a new level available

Comment: see earlier comment about local variables

Comment: Aren't I passing in the current local variable to the function?  For what it's worth, I already tried changing the name of the parameter of the function to something other than index just in case it was a scope issue, and it didn't help.

Comment: no, you're not :P  you need the loop to make a copy of variables you embed in things to be run later eg events otherwise it has the value it last had.. which is max value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is called ["capture" of variables in lambda expressions / anonymous functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions)

The `index` the moment it is used in the anonymous function/lambda (button callback) is passed as a captured **reference**!

Thus the exact same instance/memory space is used for all your callbacks, and while you go through the loop you increase it every time.

=> in all callbacks it will have its final value after the loop ended.

Solution would be to create a local variable for each loop as individual instance:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (Texture2D texture in imageTextures)
{
    Image image = Instantiate(levelSelectPrefab, levelSelectPanel);
    Button button = image.GetComponent<Button>();
/* !!! */var scopedIndex = index;
    button.onClick.AddListener(delegate { StartGame(texture, scopedIndex); });
    index++;
}
```